# Generator error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, fibonacci

I'm still new to generators in python. I was trying out one on my own and tried to something really simple:

```
def fib(a):
...     if a==0 or a==1:return 1
...     yield fib(a-1)+fib(a-2)
print(list(fib(5))
```

This code gave me this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'generator' and 'generator'
```

Can't generators be used in this manner?

Comment: Change `print(list(fib(5))` to `print(list(fib(5)))`.

Comment: Try to generate the Fibonacci sequence without recursion and it will work as a generator.

Answer (score 6):

Calling a generator function doesn't produce the next value. It produces a *generator object*, a specialist version of an iterator object. You have, in effect, something that wraps a *paused function*.

To get another value from that function, you'd have to call `next(iterator)` on the object or use something like `list(iteratort)` or `for ... in iterator` to loop over the object and get the values out. See [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do) for more details.

So here, the you'd have to use `next(fib(a-1)) + next(fib(a-2))` to get the two recursive values out. That'll also fail, because your termination case (`a == 0 or a == 1`) uses `return` (translated into the value of a `StopIteration` exception) and not `yield`; you'd have to fix that too.

And this highlights why your recursive function *should not be a generator function*. Your function doesn't produce a series of values to iterate over. There's just **one** result mfor a given argument value. You'd be far better off to just use `return` and not `yield`.

If you wanted to generate a sequence of fibonacci numbers, the function argument would need to be seen as a limit; "give me the first n fibonacci numbers". The following iterative function does that:

```
def first_n_fibonacci(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield a
```

This would give you a list of the first `n` fibonacci numbers, as a generator:

```
>>> f = first_n_fibonacci(5)
>>> f
<generator object first_n_fibonacci at 0x10b2c8678>
>>> next(f)
1
>>> next(f)
1
>>> list(f)
[2, 3, 5]
```

or you could use the argument to produce all fibonacci values up to a limit, or to produce an *endless* generator of fibonacci numbers. None of those would require recursion, a loop like the above suffices.

Comment: Oh okay i get it now, I got confused with how return works. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Generators are meant to be used for iterations, and yet by adding two of the returning values from `fib` you are trying to use it as a scalar value, which is confirmed by your terminal condition (where `a` equals to `0` or `1`) also returning a scalar value.

You should simply use `return` in this case.

```
def fib(a):
    if a==0 or a==1:return 1
    return fib(a-1)+fib(a-2)
print(fib(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use a generator, you need to think about outputting a sequence, and not a single value. Do you want your `fib(a)` to output the `a`th fib number or the the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th ... `a`th fib number? If the latter, then generators are good for this.

Here is an example generator for the Fibonacci numbers from the 1st to the `n`th number.

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```